# Is there a hereditarily disconnected space which is not the union of countably many totally disconnected subspaces?

Tags: gn.general-topology, dimension-theory

A topological space $X$ is called

$\bullet$ *totally disconnected* if for any distinct points $x,y\in X$ there exists a clopen set $U\subseteq X$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\notin U$;

$\bullet$ *hereditarily disconnected* if every connected subspace of $X$ has cardinality $\le 1$;

$\bullet$ *punctiform* if every connected compact subset of $X$ has cardinality $\le 1$.

It is well-known that $$\mbox{zero-dimensional}\Rightarrow\mbox{totally disconnected}\Rightarrow\mbox{hereditarily disconnected}\Rightarrow\mbox{punctiform}$$
and none of these implications can be reversed even in the class of separable metrizable spaces.

In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2043785) Roman Pol constructed his famous example of a Polish totally disconnected space, which is not a countable union of zero-dimensional spaces.

> **Problem 1.** *Is there a hereditarily disconnected metrizable separable (desirably Polish) space which is not a countable union of totally disconnected spaces?*

**Remark.** By Main Lemma in [this paper](https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/167/2), the Hilbert cube $Q=[0,1]^\omega$ is not a countable union of hereditarily disconnected spaces. On the other hand, for any Bernstein set $B$ in $Q$ both spaces $B$ and $Q\setminus B$ are punctiform and hence one of them is not a countable union of hereditarily disconnected spaces.

> **Problem 2.** Is there a Polish punctiform space which is not the union of countably many hereditarily disconnected spaces?

Comment: For Problem 1 are you asking both versions of the question (i.e., for a Polish example or a not necessarily Polish example)?

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes. I am asking about an example of a metrizable separable (desirably Polish) hereditarily disconnected space which is not the union of countably many totally disconnected subspaces. I have made this clarification in the question.